# Should I modify my Wordpress theme by myself?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've used (https://validator.w3.org) to validate my WP theme which I got for free from the Wordpress marketplace and I got some warnings that I want to correct.

I've got some experience in HTML and CSS. The I've got some warnings like "The header element does not need a role attribute" and "the complementary role is unnecessary for element aside"

So I want to remove those attributes and fix the warnings, my question is am I allowed to edit a free theme? And should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second the other two previous answers. Test your site in all the major browsers and unless the errors are creating a specific undesired result I wouldn't worry too much about them, particularly for a basic / smaller site.

As for editing the theme, I agree that generally child themes are the way to go. It's actually very easy to create a basic child theme. Think of it as a sandbox where you can't screw up any of the original code, and it will also allow you to update the parent theme (if the developer issues regular updates) without undoing the changes you have made.

The Wordpress Codex is always a good place to start: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

There are also plenty of other tutorials on the internet if you do some googling.

If you want to dive a little deeper and dip your toes into theme development, there are some good starter themes that are designed for you to edit the parent theme and make it your own. Though I would recommend a pretty solid understanding of HTML / CSS and a familiarity with PHP syntax before you embark on developing your own theme.

Here are a couple starter themes that I like:

- underscores.me
- Shoestrap (a starter theme that comes with Bootstrap already
  integrated)

  https://press.codes/

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn child theme concept to this , as if you will use child theme, you will still be able to update your current theme.

Answer (score 1):

W3 validator does not always give critical errors, it check against the html5 standard. Some code that fails the W3 validator can run cleanly on most browsers. Only edit your WP theme if you know what you are doing and have reason to suspect that the error/warning/notice raised by W3 validator prevents the theme from functioning (properly).